# How do I import .c4d files on Blender?

Tags: import

How can I import a .c4d static model (Cinema 4d) on Blender? Is there any plugin could help me? I didn't notice anything on Internet.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. There are so many different types of models out there (static, animated, rigged) and nobody knows what's exactly on your mind if you phrase your questions too broad. For further information, please read [this help article](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center.

Comment: You could try to download the demo version of C4D and export the model using OBJ, FBX or other format supported by Blender

Answer (score 6):

Maxon's Cinema 4D is a closed and proprietary tool and there is no way to access the .c4d file in a legal, safe and usable way other than C4D itself.

But you can use one of the many other export methods available.

".obj" , ".fbx" , ".dae" .... for simple mesh transfer and Alembic (.abc) for dynamic and advanced export.

Answer (score 4):

If, like me, you don't have Cinema 4D, but need to get a file into Blender, there is at least one online conversion facility (https://anyconv.com/c4d-converter/) that can convert the file to either .fbx or .obj, which can then be imported into Blender. It doesn't work on all files but maybe worth a try.