# How do I import .lib4d files to blender?

Tags: conversion

I just got a really cool model but it was a .lib4d model from Cinema 4D and I can't figure out how to get it into blender. Is there a way to get the model into blender without having to buy C4D or anything like that?

Comment: See here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121039/75504